# Want to exclude sonar plugin for specific project in bamboo build

Tags: maven, java-8, sonarqube, bamboo

I am supporting many teams for bamboo build including sonar. One of my team using CXX plugin .
Now we are facing issue after installing the plugin. Because many other team still depends on JDK 8 and CXX will support JDK 11. Is there any way to exclude CXX plugin for specific project or build ?
I tried -Dsonar.exclusions=/*.h,/.c,**/.hh,/*.hpp,/*.cc,.cxx,.cpp,.hxx but not success.

Error :

Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project ABC: The plugin [cxx] does not support Java 1.8.0_312: org/sonar/plugins/cxx/CxxPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 → [Help 1]